How can I calculate student positions based on total calculated score?
The screenshot shows the table I am using. I am identifying each student using learner_id and I would like to be calculating the sum of total scores for each student using the total field. Based on the sum of scores, I would like to evaluate the student positions based on highest sum of scores.

Honestly, I am just stuck, I don't know how I can actually do this

Try this query
SELECT learner_id, SUM(total) AS total_scores
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY learner_id
ORDER BY total_scores DESC;

if you want to find positions in mysql  Query only then you can try this as well
SELECT      learner_id,      SUM(total) AS total_scores,     @position := @position + 1 AS position FROM      (SELECT @position := 0) AS init,      your_table_name GROUP BY      learner_id ORDER BY      total_scores DESC;

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Is this a PHP problem or a MySQL problem?

Simplest for query is
select t.learner_id, sum(t.total) as totalscore from yourTabelName as t 
group by t.learner_id order by totalscore desc;


Thanks Naveed, this really worked. Thanks for understanding me
